# how to add array of HKQuantityType for health kit authorization

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

How can I add a second HKQuantityType to my health kit authorization?
I would like to add both the heart rate and the energy burned, as the array of QuantityTypes. When I add both of these types in the line ' let dataTypes = Set(arrayLiteral: quantityTypes)' instead of quantity type, as an array, I am getting an error "cannot convert value of HKQuantityType to expected argument type []

I am a beginner, I think I am not formatting the array correctly.

```
  guard let heartRateQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned) else {
        // displayNotAllowed()
        return
    }

    guard let calorieQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned) else {
       // displayNotAllowed()
        return
    }

    let quantityTypes = [calorieQuantityType, heartRateQuantityType]
    let dataTypes = Set(arrayLiteral: quantityTypes)
    healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(nil, readTypes: dataTypes) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success == false {
            //    self.displayNotAllowed()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the array to a Set then requesting authorisation. Instead add calorieQuantityType and heartRateQuantityType to the SET directly

```
//delete this let quantityTypes = [calorieQuantityType, heartRateQuantityType]
let dataTypes = Set([calorieQuantityType, heartRateQuantityType])
healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(nil, readTypes: dataTypes) { (success, error) -> Void in
    if success == false {
        //    self.displayNotAllowed()
    }
}
```